# When I try to install a package with npm it gives me a permission denied error

Tags: npm

When I try to install any package with npm even with sudo I get a permission denied error.

```
sudo npm install sqlite3
```

I get the following error:

```
sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
npm WARN discord.js@11.5.1 requires a peer of @discordjs/uws@^10.149.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN youbot@0.2.3 No description
npm WARN youbot@0.2.3 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! sqlite3@4.1.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-12-01T19_13_09_034Z-debug.log
```

Any help would be appriciated. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You need this package to be installed first `@discordjs/uws@^10.149.0`

Comment: Got the same error again. Any other solutions are appriciated!